# Two of the same variables in different classes

Tags: java

I could only find a c# link for this and couldn't understand it so here goes..

I have a Player and a Target class in my program, and I want to be able to make like this:

```
public Player(int difficulty)
{
    if(difficulty == 1)
        health = hArray[0];
    else
        health = hArray[1];
}
```

where hArray is my array of possible health values. This works, but I also deal with playerHealth inside of my Target class just for ease of use because I'm new to java sort of and didn't know how else to do it, so that has something like this:

```
private int playerHealth;
public int getPlayerHealth()
{
    return playerHealth;
}


public void setPlayerHealth(int playerHealth){
    this.playerHealth = playerHealth;
}
```

But I don't know how to call this anymore because originally I had it set for Player to always start with 100 health. I changed it because I need to set the option of health value in Player as a requirement and now when I call this in main (psuedo-ish):

```
Your starting health: " + tgt.getPlayerHealth()
```

It just says 0 because the health was defined in Player. So I know why it isn't working but I'm not sure how to fix it, or if I can fix it with my current layout.

Here are my declarations/instanstiations (is this a word?):

```
    Target tgt = new Target(dif);
    Player p1 = new Player(dif);
```

Based off of:

```
System.out.println("\nEnter a difficulty 1-2 (entering an integer "
            + "other than 1 or 2 will default to 2):");
dif = scn.nextInt();
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: Should really Target be a class ? To my mind, a target is simply, for a givent Player, another enemy Player. I don't get what is the use of the Target class.

Comment: needed two classes in assignment

Comment: What's a target, an enemy that fights the player the removes some of it's health, hence the need for knowing what the player's health is?

Comment: So your question is ... how do I use two classes to solve a problem whose correct solution uses just one class?

Comment: yes NES and perhaps david but I'm looking for the correct solution without using one class. I'm sure there is more than one solution for mostly every problem.. despite some going the long route

Comment: If this is a single-player game then having two classes is fine (one class for the human `Player`, one class for the IA `Target`s). However, if that is the case there is no logical relation between the health of the target and the health of the player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you properly modeled your two classes (which I doubt a bit): if your `Target` needs to know about the player health, it should have a reference to a `Player` *instance* and not hold a copy of one of the private members of `Player`. Then you'll access the player health via that instance:

```
target.getPlayer().getHealth();
target.getPlayer().setHealth(50);
```

But once a `Target` has a reference to one `Player`, the names of the classes (if not the design in its entirety) seem quite inadequate.

Answer (score 1):

After knowing that `Target` is suppose to be an entity of some kind that fights your `Player` and makes them lose their health, hence the need for target to know about player health, then I think you would want to have an operation belonging to `Player` that can fight `Target`s (just pass `Target` to `Player`, or the other way around). Something along the lines of the following would most likely work:

```
public interface Entity
{
    public int getStrength();
    public int damageThatCanBeDoneToAnotherEntity(Entity someOtherEntity);
    public int getHealth();
    public void fightAnotherEntity(Entity someOtherEntity);
}

public class WeakMonster implements Entity...
public class StrongMonster implements Entity...
public class Player implements Entity...
```

This is your homework assignment so I'll let you fill in the gaps.

Comment: I get what everyone is trying to say but I'm just going to change it so it's less of a mess and make the int difficulty refer to a different variable that is not important to the Target class... this way it'll work properly and I'll be doing the assignment properly at the same time, thanks for the answers though. The interface is something we went over/learned a little after I was already far along in the project so I didn't want to risk not finishing it because I tried to use something new.

Comment: @pbrianq Well you don't need to use a base type for both your Target type and Player type, as long as you can have one interact with the other and still redeclare similar methods it should be straight forward. I only gave you interfaces so I wouldn't have to give you code for your homework assignment.

Answer (score 0):

rather than having an array like you do with the hArray, you should create a function in Player like

`public static int getPlayerInitialHealth(int difficulty)`

then you can use that function in both of your classes (import into the second class)